# Power Query Load Selected Data from a List

Tags: microsoft-excel, power-query

I work in Logistics, and we deal with Tracking IDS.

I have heavy data of over 100k rows Containing all data related to Tracking IDs (Dump)

I have a list of tracking IDs mostly in hundreds which I have to filter out of the dump and do multiple analyses and calculations

When dealing with such data the first set of mins is very long and as the PQ needs to first load all data and then we have to filter from it. and take things from there

is there any reference or solutions on this point?

Example: Dump Table

```
R D
1 a
2 b
3 c
```

list Table

```
R D
2 b
```

I need only row 2 (b) to load to the power query table so we don't have to deal with slicing the data after load.

Comment: You question is unclear, please edit otherwise you question will get closed. If you want power query to return a subset from (I assume) a database then you would need to either hardcode the SQL query or learn to use the advance editor to have it write the SQL for you. The List.Accumulate is a function that can help with part of getting power query to write an SQL statement. Good luck.

Comment: Do you mean Power Query take long time to analyses data?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, a simple solution suggests itself.

If PQ takes a long time to load, check to see if opening as a spreadsheet takes noticeably less time. If so, in a second spreadsheet, use `FILTER` on the data using the list of needed ID's. Copy and Paste|Special|Values and save the results.

Open the second spreadsheet with PQ.

Not worthwhile if opening the data in a spreadsheet instead of PQ takes forever, or is not possible. Also, it could be physically more complex than the straightforward path above and therefore end up being obnoxious to do.

Naturally, one would suggest the source of the data pare it down as much as possible, if it is not already. Meant more as a "no unnecessary columns of data" thought than a backhanded way saying have the source filter the data for you which surely is not a viable idea. But if you can have a smaller data set due to unneeded columns not being provided...

My `GUESS` is that if you load the list to filter by, and then the data, PQ might try to work as it loads and it seems that it could take MUCH longer than loading the data, then the list. So if that is possible, it might speed up PQ. But it is a guess, and there's a hugely good chance MS thought of such an obvious thing.